# how can I find out how many rows are in kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've a kendo grid some thing like this

```
$("#HoleGrid").kendoGrid({ ... });
```

how can I find out how many rows are in grid??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the following. It should work...

```
$("#HoleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length
```

or as #Quinton Bernhardt

```
$("#HoleGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.total()
```

Comment: How do we set the total row count? for setting the data we can do something like this `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(ARRAY_OF_DATA);` But this does not allows us to set row count

Comment: I normally do a grid refresh after each row update.

Comment: I am making a ajax call on page load. the autoBind property for the page is setup as false. when i get response, it has two property. `data` & `rowCount`. i assign data using `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(response.data);`. how do i set the `rowCount` to enable paging.

Comment: Need to check before I can tell. But in your scenario I normally set the page size on js grid initialization and when I get data kendo normally do the paging itself. Are you talking about the serverside paging??

Comment: You can check this as well 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901798/get-record-count-in-kendo-grid-after-datasource-read

Comment: thank you for quick reply. my scenario is different. i only send those records i want to show on grid. when user page, i want to go to the server, get next set of records and then update the grid and total rowCount

Comment: Check this one if helps http://jsfiddle.net/rusev/Lnkug/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104325/discussion-between-mahib-and-sharpcoder).

Comment: I cannot chat. Its blocked in my organization

Comment: Also check in the api ref >> http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-pager

Answer (score 4):

```
    var grid = $("#HoleGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var count = grid.dataSource.total();
```