# How to manually set total records in Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement where a large dataset is processed at backend. As soon as first batch is processed, I request the data to be binded to grid. Everything is fine till the first binding, but total records are not shown correctly and I do not get actual number of paging buttons (or say, I cannot navigate to the next page).

I read that the total in the pager is linked to the total property of the Kendo UI grid, so in order to update its value the total of the `dataSource` should be updated as well.

I manually updated the total of the `dataSource`.

```
$('#CenterList').data("kendoGrid").dataSource._total = 50;
```

but it's of no use.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Center>()
    .Name("CenterList")
    .Pageable(pager => pager
        .Input(true)        
        .PageSizes(true)   
        .Refresh(true)
        .ButtonCount(5)
        .Numeric(true)
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(x => x.centerCode).Title("center code").Width(30).ClientTemplate(
            "<a style='cursor:pointer' onclick='EditCenter(&quot; #:centerCode# &quot; );'>#: centerCode#</a>");
        columns.Bound(x => x.centerName).Title("CenterName").Width(100);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(15)
        .Read(read => read.Action("CenterList", "Maintenance"))
        .ServerOperation(true)
    )
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))

)
```

And here is the controller

```
public ActionResult CenterList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var groupList = iCenter.GetAllCenter(request.Page, Session["InstituteCode"].ToString());
        DataSourceResult result = groupList.ToDataSourceResult(request, x => new
        {
            x.centerCode,
            x.centerName,
        });
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I can get records for first page. That is 15 rows and then I can not go to next page.

I got the total count of records and assigned the Kendo Grid `dataSource` total manually.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var total;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCenterCount","Maintenance")',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            total = data;
        }
    });
    $('#CenterList').data("kendoGrid").dataSource._total = total;

    alert("Total in ds = " + $('#CenterList').data("kendoGrid").dataSource._total);
});
```

The total is good till the alert shows. But afterwards, Kendo Grid does not show the total `rowCount` or the next page.

Comment: Are you trying to do something different than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901798/get-record-count-in-kendo-grid-after-datasource-read) ?

Comment: Anaya, could you show how you perform your binding of the first batch on the server-side? or is it done on the client-side?

Comment: @SteveGreene I used the alert to get the total of the datasource and it is correct but the grid does not display anything like that instead it says the total is just as the total number of records of the first page.

Comment: Take a look at this article about [custom server binding](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/custom-binding), which uses `ViewData` to store the `total`. It is possible to return a `DataSourceResult` aswell by specifying `Data` and `Total` objects ([Custom Ajax Binding](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/binding/custom-binding#configuration-Apply)).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Sandman, I am not using EntityFramework here. I simply am not getting the idea why the pagination is not working. I mean I supplied it manually and its returning the value but is not applied to the KendoGrid. I wrote the sql that returns records for a single page (say, 15 rows) so that it would be easy to return the records for their respective pages.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you are using EF or SQL, as long as the data being returned is structured correctly (as a `DataSourceResult` containing `Data` and `Total` attributes).

Comment: I used ViewData as instructed in the article. But it remained the same. Neither did it showed the total number of records nor the grid showed more than one page.